# Model already contains an attribute 'trigger'. Skip binding

Tags: python, state-machine, pytransitions

I want to implement state machine for my `Order` model, and I am using this beautiful [pytransitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) library. But I am facing this strange issue.

This is my `order.py` with model:

```
from order_state_machine import OrderStateMachine

class Order(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, order_dict):
        super().__init__(order_dict)
        # next line basically creates Customer object inside Order model
        self.set('customer', Customer(order_dict['customer']))
        self.machine = OrderStateMachine(self)
```

This my `order_state_machine.py`:

```
from transitions import Machine

class OrderStateMachine(Machine):
    order_states = ['pending', 'paid', 'shipped', 'delivered', 'canceled']

    order_transitions = [
        {'trigger': 'pay', 'source': 'pending', 'dest': 'paid'},
        {'trigger': 'deliver', 'source': 'shipped', 'dest': 'delivered'},
        {'trigger': 'cancel', 'source': 'shipped', 'dest': 'canceled'},
    ]

    def __init__(self, order):
        super().__init__(
            model=order,
            states=OrderStateMachine.order_states,
            transitions=OrderStateMachine.order_transitions,
            initial='pending'
        )
```

And when I do:

```
from order import Order

new_order = Order(order_dict)

new_order.state  # returns 'pending'
new_order.pay()
new_order.state  # I expect 'paid'
```

It, `new_order.pay()` line, gives me `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error. And also a `Model already contains an attribute 'trigger'. Skip binding.` warning, and a lot of warnings like this.

Could someone help me to resolve this problem, may be maintainers of the library. Thanks.

Comment: I assume it has something to do with `some_dict`. Could you provide some Info about the keys you are passing? If I omit `some_dict` everything runs smooth.

Comment: @aleneum, first, thanks for quick reply. second, i changed it to closest to original code.

Comment: @aleneum `order_dict` is a JSON

Comment: Do you also see a 'Model already contains an attribute 'pay'. Skip binding'?

Comment: @aleneum, yes yes. a lot of them))

Comment: @aleneum, we were discussing that, may be the way we are trying is not a good solution. I mean doing `class OrderStateMachine(Machine):` and then `self.machine = OrderStateMachine(self)` seems cleaner but may be it is wrong way. IDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell with one hundred percent certainty but I assume your `BaseModel` already contains attributes and methods that overlap with methods that `transitions` wants to dynamically decorate your model with.

`transitions` will do a 'checked' assignment which means it will only assign triggers and convenience functions to a model when the desired name is not already taken by existing attributes or methods. The reason behind this is that sometimes people do not care about the triggers and call functions exclusively by their name (using the `trigger` method actually).

I assume your `BaseModel` contains an attribute assignment similarly to [1] as seen below.

```py
from transitions import Machine
import logging


class BaseModel:

    def __init__(self, order_dict):
        self.pay = None  # [1] already defined attribute

    def trigger(self):  # [2] already defined method
        pass


class OrderStateMachine(Machine):
    order_states = ['pending', 'paid', 'shipped', 'delivered', 'canceled']

    order_transitions = [
        {'trigger': 'pay', 'source': 'pending', 'dest': 'paid'},
        {'trigger': 'deliver', 'source': 'shipped', 'dest': 'delivered'},
        {'trigger': 'cancel', 'source': 'shipped', 'dest': 'canceled'},
    ]

    def __init__(self, order):
        super().__init__(
            model=order,
            states=OrderStateMachine.order_states,
            transitions=OrderStateMachine.order_transitions,
            initial='pending'
        )


class Order(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, order_dict):
        super().__init__(order_dict)
        self.machine = OrderStateMachine(self)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
# [2] will cause 'Model already contains an attribute 'trigger'. Skip binding.'
new_order = Order({})  
new_order.state  # returns 'pending'
# [1] will cause a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
new_order.pay()
new_order.state
```

To deal with this you should make sure that trigger names and model attributes are mutually exclusive to prevent naming collisions. If you did define all those methods on purpose -- for instance to drop some code completion hints to your IDE -- and you REALLY want to keep it that way you can override the `Machine._checked_assignment` method:

```
class OveriddingMachine(Machine):

    # assign everything to the model ignoring already existing attributes
    def _checked_assignment(self, model, name, func):
        setattr(model, name, func)
```

Note that if you do that your machine might mess with your model in undesired ways.

Comment: actually we don't have neither `pay` nor `trigger` methods in BaseModel. But this solution solved the problem. Of course we will investigate it little bit more. Anyways thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Eziz Durdyyev, I see. It's worth investigating then where the attributes come from. Maybe the model is initialized twice? I'd set a breakpoint on `_checked_assignment` and have a look where it is actually called and to check the current model state. Otherwise this might shoot you in the knee later.

Comment: I totally agree. may be we are creating it twice. this was a big help. thanks again!!!